# How to remove the space between a shape (inside table) and the bottom margin of the cell in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a shape inside one cell of a table. The shape should attach to the top and bottom of the cell, I mean, there should be exactly no space between the shape and top/bottom of the cell.
For example, in the shape bellow:

[This image displays space between shape and cell top/bottom margins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85bS7.png)

there is no space between the triangle and the top margin of the cell, but a little space is between the triangle and the bottom margin of the cell. How can I remove this space (between the triangle and the bottom margin)?

Please consider that I have set the "top/bottom cell margins to 0 (zero)" and the shape is "in line with text".

Thanks a lot.

Word version 2013.

Comment: I don't think that is possible with an inline shape inserted into a table cell. The space I see in my test is 1-point, and there is 1-point at the top, it just visually looks like it is touching ... but I don't think it actually is touching the cell border.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't find any way to remove this space, yet! But, changing the wrap format of the shape to "In front of text" partially solves the problem!